# The following code returns an 500 error as the code is deprecited in php version 7, How to make it work in php verison 7?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the code that used but return the 500 error in php version 7 and I totally screwed what to do with and could not find any documentation to do so.

```html
<?php
// Create a new MySQL database connection
if (!$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password')) {
die('An error occurred while connecting to the MySQL server!<br><br>' . mysql_error());
}

if (!mysql_select_db(sample)) {
die('An error occurred while connecting to the database!<br><br>' . mysql_error());
}

// Create an array of MySQL queries to run
$sql = array(
'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS content;',
'CREATE TABLE content SELECT * FROM sample1.content'
);

// Run the MySQL queries
if (sizeof($sql) > 0) {
foreach ($sql as $query) {
if (!mysql_query($query)) {
die('A MySQL error has occurred!<br><br>' . mysql_error());
}
}
}

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Simple, you can't *make it work*. `mysql_*` functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. Also learn about [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: `mysql_*` functions were deprecated practically an eternity ago... See: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a good tutorial about converting deprecated `mysql_*` PHP code to new `mysqli_*` code:

http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/9199/post/3-Smoothly-Migrate-your-PHP-Code-using-the-Old-MySQL-extension-to-MySQLi.html

In many cases, you simply need to change "mysql" to "mysqli" for each function call.

Remember to change them all!

Answer (score 4):

You are using an deprecated implementation of mysql that have been removed in php7.

> Warning
>   This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
>   mysqli_query()
>   PDO::query()

please check http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php